# Why does GetWindowRect include the title bar in my WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke, caret

I'm trying to get caret position using `GetWindowRect()` (and `GetGUIThreadInfo()`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CaretInfo
    {
        public double Width { get; private set; }
        public double Height { get; private set; }
        public double Left { get; private set; }
        public double Top { get; private set; }

        public CaretInfo(double width, double height, double left, double top)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
        }
    }

    public class CaretHelper
    {

        public static CaretInfo GetCaretPosition()
        {
            // Get GUI info containing caret poisition
            var guiInfo = new GUITHREADINFO();
            guiInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(guiInfo);
            GetGUIThreadInfo(0, out guiInfo);

            // Get width/height
            double width = guiInfo.rcCaret.right - guiInfo.rcCaret.left;
            double height = guiInfo.rcCaret.bottom - guiInfo.rcCaret.top;

            // Get left/top relative to screen
            RECT rect;
            GetWindowRect(guiInfo.hwndFocus, out rect);

            double left = guiInfo.rcCaret.left + rect.left + 2;
            double top = guiInfo.rcCaret.top + rect.top + 2;


            int capacity = GetWindowTextLength(guiInfo.hwndFocus) * 2;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
            GetWindowText(guiInfo.hwndFocus, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
            Console.WriteLine("Window: " + stringBuilder);
            Console.WriteLine("Caret: " + guiInfo.rcCaret.left + ", " + guiInfo.rcCaret.top);
            Console.WriteLine("Rect : " + rect.left + ", " + rect.top);

            return new CaretInfo(width, height, left, top);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetGUIThreadInfo")]
        public static extern bool GetGUIThreadInfo(uint tId, out GUITHREADINFO threadInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, out Point position);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct GUITHREADINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint flags;
            public IntPtr hwndActive;
            public IntPtr hwndFocus;
            public IntPtr hwndCapture;
            public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
            public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
            public IntPtr hwndCaret;
            public RECT rcCaret;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetWindowTextLe
```

For Notepad and almost anywhere else the coordinates are correctly fetched:

[image]

In my WPF (and any other WPF) window, however, `GetWindowRect()` decides to include the title bar and offsetting the caret top position by the height of the title bar:

[image]

Any idea why?

I tried using `DwmGetWindowAttribute()` as well, but it gets the same coordinates for the WPF window as `GetWindowRect()`.

*Edit:*

With the answer from [Brian Reichle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274204/brian-reichle) I've been able to determine a way to get the coordinate of the client area:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref System.Drawing.Point lpPoint);

System.Drawing.Point point = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
ClientToScreen(guiInfo.hwndFocus, ref point)
```

`0,0` is the top left coordinate of the client area of the window specified by `guiInfo.hwndFocus` and it's always `0,0` because it's relative to the window's client area. `ClientToScreen()` converts the coordinates to be relative to screen instead (has to be `System.Drawing.Point`, `System.Windows.Point` won't work).

Comment: The titlebar is included because its part of the window, if you don't want the non-client area then you need to request the client area rect (GetClientRect). The confusion from notepad is probably because you are using the window handle of the text box rather than of the window itself. Remember WPF uses a single handle for the overall window while win32 will often (but not always) use a separate handle for each control within the window.

Comment: `GetClientRect()` returns 0,0, but I think you're correct about the window handles - I can confirm with Spy++ at least, so if you want to drop that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title bar is included because its part of the window, if you don't want the non-client area then you need to request the client area rect (`GetClientRect`).

The confusion from notepad is probably because you are using the window handle of the text box rather than of the window itself. Remember, WPF uses a single handle for the overall window while win32 will often (but not always) use a separate handle for each control within the window.

In a comment you mentioned that `GetClientRect` 'returned' `0,0`, did you check if it returned true (success) or false (failure)? If it returned false, did you check the result of `GetLastError()`?

Comment: Apparently `GetClientRect()` is working as intended - it's relative to the client area of the window's client area, so `left`/`top` are always `0,0`. The correct function to use is `ClientToScreen()` (I've updated my question to show how).

Comment: That's correct. The client rectangle's top-left point is always at (0, 0). `ClientToScreen()` will work, or use the more generic `MapWindowPoints`. However, @woodgnome, your question says that you want the "caret position". This code will give you the screen coordinates of the window's client area, but the caret might not be in the top-left corner.

Comment: I use `GUITHREADINFO.rcCaret` to offset the caret position - `GetClientRect()` just caused me some issues and I've replaced that with `ClientToScreen()` instead.